# Summarizing data for each month

Tags: r, summary

I've got a following table in csv:

| Date | Results |
| --- | --- |
| 2015/09/01 | 1 811 |
| 2015/09/03 | 1 009 |
| 2015/09/20 | 1 889 |
| 2015/10/03 | 1 139 |
| 2015/10/06 | 1 275 |

I would like to summarize values from "result" for each month and convert them into a bar chart.
I cannot find any sum function to fit my problem which can summarize by year and month ignoring days in the month.

I should look like this (except yellow bar):

[image: barchart]

Answer (score 1):

Probably answered somehwere else too... magic is to convert your Date to a Date format and then extract the month from it... this might do the trick:

```
data <- data.frame(Results =c(1811, 1009, 1889, 1139, 1275), 
              Date = c("01.09.15", "03.09.15", "20.09.15", "03.10.15", "06.10.15"))

data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date,format = "%d.%m.%y")

library(lubridate)
data$Month <- month(data$Date,label=T)

aggregate(data= data,Results~Month, FUN = sum)
```

leads to:

```
  Month Results
   Sep    4709
   Oct    2414
```

for plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(data=data, x = Month, y=Results, geom="col")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here a `tidyverse` approach that might help you

```
data <- 
  structure(list(Results = c(1811, 1009, 1889, 1139, 1275),
                 Date = c("01.09.15","03.09.15", "20.09.15", "03.10.15", "06.10.15")),
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))


library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  mutate(
    Date = dmy(Date),
    Month = month(Date,label = TRUE),
    Year = year(Date)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Year,Month) %>% 
  summarise(Results = sum(Results,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month,Results))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution but if all you want to do is plot the values you don’t even need to summarise the data manually — ‘ggplot2’ has got your back: `data |>
mutate(Month = floor_date(dmy(Date), 'month')) |>
ggplot(aes(x = Month)) +
geom_bar()`